# get 502 bad gateway error when calling a webservice

Tags: soap, jboss, web-services

In my SEAM web application running under JBOSS-AS 4.2.3 there is a plain SOAP message call to a webservice, using SOAPConnection.call().
The call ends up with a
org.jboss.remoting.CannotConnectException: **Can not connect http client invoker. Invalid HTTP server response [502] - Bad Gateway**.

Running the same code outside the JBOSS as a pure java application all works fine.

So question: Is there something in JBoss I have to configure that makes things work ?

Thx for answers,
Frank